# css being ignored in ie8/9, not at selector limit

Tags: css, internet-explorer

trying to figure out why ie keeps ignoring my css.  My selectors are only at 3494, my file size is 960KB, and there are 15600 lines before being ignored, but minifying to less lines has no effect.

Works fine in ie10, firefox, chrome.

All of that said, everything I've read is that there is only a selector limit, import nesting limit, and stylesheet limit.

Any ideas?

It is choking on on the arrowthick styles.  I was able to get it to stop at different places by moving some things around, so I doubt it is syntax.

here is the stuff that gets skipped off the end,

```
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n{background-position:0 -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne{background-position:-16px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e{background-position:-32px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-se{background-position:-48px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s{background-position:-64px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-sw{background-position:-80px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w{background-position:-96px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-nw{background-position:-112px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s{background-position:-128px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw{background-position:-144px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-e-w{background-position:-160px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-se-nw{background-position:-176px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-n{background-position:-192px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e{background-position:-208px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s{background-position:-224px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w{background-position:-240px -48px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w{background-position:0 -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-n{background-position:-16px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-e{background-position:-32px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-s{background-position:-48px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-w{background-position:-64px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n{background-position:-80px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e{background-position:-96px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s{background-position:-112px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w{background-position:-128px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n{background-position:-144px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e{background-position:-160px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s{background-position:-176px -64px}
.ui-icon-arrow-4{background-position:0 -80px}
.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag{background-position:-16px -80px}
.ui-icon-extlink{background-position:-32px -80px}
.ui-icon-newwin{background-position:-48px -80px}
.ui-icon-refresh{background-position:-64px -80px}
.ui-icon-shuffle{background-position:-80px -80px}
.ui-icon-transfer-e-w{background-position:-96px -80px}
.ui-icon-transferthick-e-w{background-position:-112px -80px}
.ui-icon-folder-collapsed{background-position:0 -96px}
.ui-icon-folder-open{background-position:-16px -96px}
.ui-icon-document{background-position:-32px -96px}
.ui-icon-document-b{background-position:-48px -96px}
.ui-icon-note{background-position:-64px -96px}
.ui-icon-mail-closed{background-position:-80px -96px}
.ui-icon-mail-open{background-position:-96px -96px}
.ui-icon-suitcase{background-position:-112px -96px}
.ui-icon-comment{background-position:-128px -96px}
.ui-icon-person{background-position:-144px -96px}
.ui-icon-print{background-position:-160px -96px}
.ui-icon-trash{background-position:-176px -96px}
.ui-icon-locked{background-position:-192px -96px}
.ui-icon-unlocked{background-position:-208px -96px}
.ui-icon-bookmark{background-position:-224px -96px}
.ui-icon-tag{background-position:-240px -96px}
.ui-icon-home{background-position:0 -112px}
.ui-icon-flag{background-position:-16px -112px}
.ui-icon-calendar{background-position:-32px -112px}
.ui-icon-cart{background-position:-48px -112px}
.ui-icon-pencil{background-position:-64px -112px}
.ui-icon-clock{background-position:-80px -112px}
.ui-icon-disk{background-position:-96px -112px}
.ui-icon-calculator{background-position:-112px -112px}
.ui-icon-zoomin{background-position:-128px -112px}
.ui-icon-zoomout{background-position:-144px -112px}
.ui-icon-search{background-position:-160px -112px}
.ui-icon-wrench{background-position:-176px -112px}
.ui-icon-gear{background-position:-192px -112px}
.ui-icon-heart{background-position:-208px -112px}
.ui-icon-star{background-position:-224px -112px}
.ui-icon-link{background-position:-240px -112px}
.ui-icon-cancel{background-position:0 -128px}
.ui-icon-plus{background-position:-16px -128px}
.ui-icon-plusthick{background-position:-32px -128px}
.ui-icon-minus{background-position:-48px -128px}
.ui-icon-minusthick{background-position:-64px -128px}
.ui-icon-close{background-position:-80px -128px}
.ui-icon-closethick{background-position:-96px -128px}
.ui-icon-key{background-position:-112px -128px}
.ui-icon-lightbulb{background-position:-128px -128px}
.ui-icon-scissors{background-position:-144px -128px}
.ui-icon-clipboard{background-position:-160px -128px}
.ui-icon-copy{background-position:-176px -128px}
.ui-icon-contact{background-position:-192px -128px}
.ui-icon-image{background-position:-208px -128px}
.ui-icon-video{background-position:-224px -128px}
.ui-icon-script{background-position:-240px -128px}
.ui-icon-alert{background-position:0 -144px}
.ui-icon-info{background-position:-16px -144px}
.ui-icon-notice{background-position:-32px -144px}
.ui-icon-help{background-position:-48px -144px}
.ui-icon-check{background-position:-64px -144px}
.ui-icon-bullet{background-position:-80px -144px}
.ui-icon-radio-on{background-position:-96px -144px}
.ui-icon-radio-off{background-position:-112px -144px}
.ui-icon-pin-w{background-position:-128px -144px}
.ui-icon-pin-s{background-position:-144px -144px}
.ui-icon-play{background-position:0 -160px}
.ui-icon-pause{background-position:-16px -160px}
.ui-icon-seek-next{background-position:-32px -160px}
.ui-icon-seek-prev{background-position:-48px -160px}
.ui-icon-seek-end{background-position:-64px -160px}
.ui-icon-seek-start{background-position:-80px -160px}
.ui-icon-seek-first{background-position:-80px -160px}
.ui-icon-stop{background-position:-96px -160px}
.ui-icon-eject{background-position:-112px -160px}
.ui-icon-volume-off{background-position:-128px -160px}
.ui-icon-volume-on{background-position:-144px -160px}
.ui-icon-power{background-position:0 -176px}
.ui-icon-signal-diag{background-position:-16px -176px}
.ui-icon-signal{background-position:-32px -176px}
.ui-icon-battery-0{background-position:-48px -176px}
.ui-icon-battery-1{background-position:-64px -176px}
.ui-icon-battery-2{background-position:-80px -176px}
.ui-icon-battery-3{background-position:-96px -176px}
.ui-icon-circle-plus{background-position:0 -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-minus{background-position:-16px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-close{background-position:-32px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e{background-position:-48px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s{background-position:-64px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w{background-position:-80px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n{background-position:-96px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e{background-position:-112px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s{background-position:-128px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w{background-position:-144px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n{background-position:-160px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-zoomin{background-position:-176px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-zoomout{background-position:-192px -192px}
.ui-icon-circle-check{background-position:-208px -192px}
.ui-icon-circlesmall-plus{background-position:0 -208px}
.ui-icon-circlesmall-minus{background-position:-16px -208px}
.ui-icon-circlesmall-close{background-position:-32px -208px}
.ui-icon-squaresmall-plus{background-position:-48px -208px}
.ui-icon-squaresmall-minus{background-position:-64px -208px}
.ui-icon-squaresmall-close{background-position:-80px -208px}
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical{background-position:0 -224px}
.ui-icon-grip-dotted-horizontal{background-position:-16px -224px}
.ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical{background-position:-32px -224px}
.ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal{background-position:-48px -224px}
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se{background-position:-64px -224px}
.ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se{background-position:-80px -224px}
.ui-corner-all,.ui-corner-top,.ui-corner-left,.ui-corner-tl{border-top-left-radius:4px}
.ui-corner-all,.ui-corner-top,.ui-corner-right,.ui-corner-tr{border-top-right-radius:4px}
.ui-corner-all,.ui-corner-bottom,.ui-corner-left,.ui-corner-bl{border-bottom-left-radius:4px}
.ui-corner-all,.ui-corner-bottom,.ui-corner-right,.ui-corner-br{border-bottom-right-radius:4px}
.ui-widget-overlay{background:#666 url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat;opacity:.5;filter:Alpha(Opacity=50)}
.ui-widget-shadow{margin:-5px 0 0 -5px;padding:5px;background:#000 url(images/ui-bg_flat_10_000000_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;opacity:.2;filter:Alpha(Opacity=20);border-radius:5px}
```

Comment: Is it ignoring the entire sheet? Or only certain rules?

Comment: Bits are cheap throw some code our way. Preferably the ones that are being ignored. Also may want to throw !important on the ends to see if you are overwriting the css somewhere else plugin file possibly.

Comment: It seems likely that there is a syntax error in your CSS file that stops parsing the rest of the file.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console? do you have any javascript in use on the site that might affect your styling? do you see anything in the dev tools? Does the same thing happen in IE10?

Comment: Oh, and if size is an issue, minifying won't have any effect; the limits are based on the number of styles/selectors, not on the file size.

Comment: Try to validate your css here: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_upload

Comment: no errors in console, doubt it is syntax, works fine in ie10, firefox, chrome, agree on the size thing, but what else could be happening

Comment: there are 13 errors in the file, I can try to fix those

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

Fix all syntax errors:

```
.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag{background-position:-16px -80px}
```

needs to have a semicolumn

```
.ui-icon-arrow-4-diag{background-position:-16px -80px;}
```

A bunch of those errors could cause problems.

Comment: it doesnt suprise with 960k of css, thats insane anyway.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately we don't have the capital to fix it. 5 years of several dozen contractors will do that to a codebase.

Comment: still occuring though

Comment: it get's cut off at a different spot, I am wondering if I am hitting the selector limit but the tool I'm using to determine the selectors is wrong

Comment: if its the limit why not split the file in 2 files?

Comment: that is possible, but I am more interested in the why

Comment: at the end of the day splitting the file into two part corrected everything, but as mentioned only 3494 selectors

Comment: So I answered the question! If you are really interested you can dig in the IE bug directory, to see if its already reported.